# using ajax to fetch a result from php and reload page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have been working on this for hours now, I have read a bunch of StackOverflow posts and I am still having no luck.

I have a page that has 2 sections to it, depending on the int in the database will depend on which section is being displayed at which time.

My goal is to have the page look to see if the database status has changed from the current one and if it has then refresh the page, if not then do nothing but re-run every 10 seconds.

I run PHP at the top of my page that gets the int from the database

```
 $online_status = Online_status::find_by_id(1);
```

I then use HTML to load the status into something that jquery can access

```
 <input type="hidden" id="statusID" value="<?php echo $online_status->status; ?>">
<span id="result"></span>
```

So at the bottom of my page, I added some jquery and ajax

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(function liveCheck(){
       var search = $('#statusID').val();
       $.ajax({
         url:'check_live.php',
         data:{search:search},
         type:'POST',
         success:function(data){
           if(!data.error){
             $newResult = $('#result').html(data);
             window.setInterval(function(){
               liveCheck();
              }, 10000); 
           }
        }
     });
   });
 liveCheck();
 });
```

this then goes to another PHP page that runs the following code

```
 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $current_status = $_POST['search'];
    $online_status = Online_status::find_by_id(1);
    if($current_status != $online_status->status){
       echo "<script>location.reload()&semi;</script>";
    }else{
    }
  }
```

the jquery then loads into the HTML section with the id of "result" as shown earlier. I know this is a very bad way to do this, and as a result, it will work at the beginning but the longer you leave it on the page the slower the page gets, till it just freezes.

If anyone is able to point me towards a proper method I would be very grateful. 
Thank you!!

Comment: Try adjusting the PHP file to return true or false. Then if you get true, you reload the page from javascript itself instead of inserting a new script tag with 1 line of javascript

Comment: I updated the PHP to return true but I cant get the ajax to only refresh if it is true, it either does it all that time or not at all

Comment: If data == true

Comment: I tried that, I had PHP return true, I had it echo 'true' I had the JS if data == true, I had it if data == 'true' still nothing

Comment: Echo an actual boolean and not as a string. Can you try console.log (data) and share the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```
(function(){
    function liveCheck(){
        var search = $('#statusID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'check_live.php',
            data:{search:search},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
            if(data.trim() == ''){
                location.reload();
            }else{
                $('#result').html(data);
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    liveCheck();
                }, 10000); 
            }
            }
        });
    }

    $(function(){
        liveCheck();
    });
})(jQuery)
```

php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $current_status = $_POST['search'];
    $online_status = Online_status::find_by_id(1);
    if($current_status != $online_status->status){
    $data = '';
    }else{
        $data = 'some html';
    }
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: I tried running that code and nothing happens, regardless of what I change the status to it does not refresh the page.

Comment: sorry, modified : data.trim == ''  correct to  data.trim()==''

Comment: page still does not refresh, weird one eh

Comment: i tested the code is all right,  when your php echo empty string will refresh the current page else show the html get from php.   For more info you need print out what error you got from browser or browser's console log. You need check your network request from console

Comment: I just used the console.log(data) and it is printing out my entire top of the page, header, and navigation. How is it getting all that data?

Comment: this may be url error, confirm check_live.php this is correct or direct view it in browser

Comment: so I was including my header in the check_live.php page as it had all my classes in it. I removed that and I only have a file to all my classes in now. I checked and the page is still accessing my db through the classes. However now when i log to the console I get nothing, I entered a string for $data in both parts of the php and stopped the refresh so I could see the log. I get the log entries but nothing is in the log

Comment: Your code is good, I forgot to uncomment the hidden input on my page!!Why is it always the simple things that cause the biggest trouble?

Comment: ok, this problem can checkout from network request log, confirm what data post to the server

Answer (score 1):

Your page is slowing down because you are creating a new interval every time you call the `liveCheck` function. Over time, you have many intervals running and sending requests to your PHP file concurrently. You can verify this behavior by opening the developer console in your browser and monitoring the Network tab.

What you should do instead is set the interval once, and perform the `$.ajax` call inside that interval. Additionally, it's good practice to not send a new request if a current request is pending, by implementing a `boolean` state variable that is true while an request is pending and false when that request completes.

It looks like the intended behavior of your function is to just reload the page when the `$online_status->status` changes, is that correct? If so, change your PHP to just echo `true` or `1` (anything really) and rewrite your JS as:

```
function liveCheck() {
    if (liveCheckPending == true)
        return;
    liveCheckPending = true;
    var search = $('#statusID').val();
    $.ajax({
         url:'check_live.php',
         data:{search:search},
         type:'POST'
     }).done(function(data){
         if (!data.error)
            location.reload();
     }).always(function(data){
         liveCheckPending = false;
     });
}

var liveCheckPending = false;
setInterval(liveCheck, 10000);
```

Comment: I updated my code to match your js, I changed my php to return true and then tried it with echo true and the page just keeps reloading, it shouldn't reload unless the php condition is true.

Comment: Change `if (!data.error)` to `if (data)` and try again.

Comment: You get the basic idea, though. Perhaps just have it echo the string `true` instead of the boolean value `true`  and then have the conditional check for `if (data == "true")`. The PHP script should be outputting nothing at all if the status hasn't changed, and anything printable if it has. You can check what the PHP script is sending back to you by viewing the Network tab in the Developer Console in your browser.

Comment: Since the last post I have been trying it with true in quotesl, this is what I have now and it does not reload, so I am guessing that I am getting something else back from the PHP, my console does not show anything.

Comment: function liveCheck() {
    if (liveCheckPending == true)
        return;
    liveCheckPending = true;
    var search = $('#statusID').val();
    $.ajax({
         url:'check_live.php',
         data:{search:search},
         type:'POST'
     }).done(function(data){
         if(data == 'true'){
            location.reload();
         }
     }).always(function(data){
         liveCheckPending = false;
     });
}

     var liveCheckPending = false;
     setInterval(liveCheck, 2000);

Comment: WOW well your code does work!!! I was looking through my code again and found that I commented out the hidden input with the status on the page. I have been working on this for a long time and missed it, thank you for your help

Comment: I would recommend not accepting the other answer as the solution as it contains the same recursive `setInterval` problem as your original post.